# Printing log-data with ADB/Unity and OculusGo/gearVR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb, oculusgo

I have a problem while developing VR-Applications. I am creating a game, and the only way to test it is building and uploading it on the Oculus Go. I could live with that, right until now where I have a problem with the behaviour of the controller. I want to log some sensor data, but due to the fact that the app is builded and started on the device, Unity can of course not read any output from it.

My workaround is to display the log data in the VR, which is really annoying. I was thinking about something like running ADB on the computer while the app is running (Oculus Go has the same core as the GearVR does, Android based), but I couldn't manage that either, mainly because the code is written in C# in Unity and I don't know if its translated correctly to the Android Log Commands.

Comment: When you say "*I couldn't manage that either*", do you mean that you couldn't get adb to run or that you had logcat running and generating a log but your messages weren't in it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for debugging and seeing the output from `Debug.log()` from the oculus go:

```
 adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager DEBUG *your log tag here*
```